# How to query data only when component is in viewport using React and React Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a React page that renders a list of post components and for each post component, I am fetching the comments related to that post and displaying them inside it using the React Query library. The problem is when the user loads the posts page, React Query is loading all the comments for all the posts at once, which causes my backend to go slow.

I want to implement a mechanism where comments are loaded only when the user scrolls to that particular post instead of loading everything at once when the page renders. How can I achieve this using React and React Query?

Here's my current sample code to fetch and display comments:

My Post Component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const PostComponent = ({ post }) => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery(
    ['comments', post.id],
    () => fetchComments(post.id)
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your post component */}
      {isLoading && <div>Loading comments...</div>}
      {error && <div>Error fetching comments</div>}
      {data && (
       <div><p>{post.title}</p> </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

My Post page Component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const PostsPage = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery('posts', fetchPosts);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <div>Loading posts...</div>}
      {error && <div>Error fetching posts</div>}
      {data &&
        data.map((post) => (
          <PostComponent key={post.id} post={post} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you familiar with intersection observer? You could use it in conjunction with the `enabled` param of `useQuery` https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries.

Comment: can you please direct me to a guide or tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this goal, you would need two components.

1. [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) - for determent if the component is in viewport
2. [React Query Dependent Queries](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries) (enabled flag) - to enable the use query when the component is in the view port

For simplified interaction with the `Intersection Observer API` in react app, you should use the `useInView` hook from [`react-intersection-observer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer) library.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

const PostComponent = ({ post }) => {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery(
    ["comments", post.id],
    () => fetchComments(post.id),
    // the useQuery hook will fetch only when inView is enabled
    { enabled: inView }
  );

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {isLoading && <div>Loading comments...</div>}
      {error && <div>Error fetching comments</div>}
      {data && (
        <div>
          <p>{post.title}</p>{" "}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

See more:

- [Live demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-query-forked-eyg3hc?file=/src/posts.tsx)